# Making touchpad and resume password changes permanent

Tags: 10.10, password, touchpad, lock-screen

in Ubuntu 10.10 I really don't want any password on resume on my EeePC, so I have to run

`gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/suspend false`

and I want two finger middle click, so I have to run

`xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 8, 9, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3`
(that gpointingdevice package can't do anything for me)

Those work, but only until the next resume. For some strange reason Ubuntu always overrides these changes.

I put both commands into a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` , but even then after resumes the changes are gone.

Where is this strange behavior coming from? And how do I make those changes permanent?

Comment: I'm not even able to comment anymore because I spent all my reputation on this bounty, but the answer that was auto-selected does not help at all. This is an unsolved and very annoying problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could add those commands in sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/suspend false
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 8, 9, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3
```

save it as startup.sh(for example) and put it in System->Preferences->Startup Applications.
Oh and add permission executing this file as program in file context menu->Permissions

Comment: This answer is off the mark. He's asking about running a script on resume, because the touchpad settings get reset after resuming from sleep. /etc/pm/sleep.d/ doesn't work, because it probably runs too early.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware that all sleep.d script run as root and could easily be the problem here.

- You can add debugging information to your script such as `echo "Touchpad command"` which will then appear in the logs. [More info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pm-utils#Creating_your_own_hooks)
- Open the logs by using **Log File Viewer** and find ***pm-suspend.log*** then search for the echo comments you added to your script and look for any errors.
- If you need help deciphering the logs copy and paste them to [dpaste](http://dpaste.com/) and paste that link here.
- You may be able to run these commands as another user with `su username -c command`

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu Oneiric, you should use the new [hotplug-command hook](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2011/03/custom-input-device-configuration-in.html).  Basically, you create a script using [this template](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/plugins/common/input-device-example.sh) that calls xinput with your desired settings somewhere in your path, make it executable, and then:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.input-devices hotplug-command <script>
```

The script will be called on startup, resume, and whenever the device is plugged/unplugged.

Answer (score 1):

I just added this as /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_touchpad (don't forget to chmod +x.) Works fine in Debian Wheezy so it should work the same in recent Ubuntu versions:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
case "${1}" in
        hibernate)
                ;;
        resume|thaw)
        DISPLAY=:0.0 su <username> -c /home/<username>/touchpad.sh
                ;;
esac
```

Substitute your own user name of course. My touchpad.sh (which is also called via "Startup Applications") is

```
#!/bin/bash
dev="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
# Use xinput --list-props "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" to list data
xinput set-prop "$dev" "Synaptics Tap Action" 8, 9, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3
xinput set-prop "$dev" "Synaptics Locked Drags" 1
xinput set-prop "$dev" "Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout" 500
```

to set locked dragging and two-finger middle click.